# Autohotkey - How do I detect if the mouse cursor changed to a text cursor?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to know whether the mouse cursor has changed to a text cursor and to activate new actions for it.

The code below:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe

/* I want to put the if statement here; if not text cursor then the following would be activated */

Left::
{
  SendInput, ^+{Tab} ; Navigate one tab back in chrome
}
return

Right::
{
  SendInput, ^{Tab} ; Navigate one tab forward in chrome
}
return

/* End of the if statement */

#IfWinActive
```

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

There is built-in variable for that.

`A_Cursor` - https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Cursor

In your case, you most likely are interested in checking if it stores `IBeam` value.

So, example:

```
#If WinActive("ahk_exe chrome.exe") and (A_Cursor != "IBeam")
Left::
    SendInput, ^+{Tab} ; Navigate one tab back in chrome
return
(...)
```

Side note, as you see above, you don't brackets when defining hotkeys.